# How do I remove a flash video completely after the video was called by swfobject

Tags: jquery, swfobject, youtube-api

Via SWFobject and AJAX I put in a video to a certain `<div>`.

Using jQuery I tried this:

```
$('#youtubepreview').html('');
```

However that didn't remove it at all - the video still stayed right there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$("#youtubepreview object").remove();
```

Comment: Struggled with it - and then an epiphany. When swfobject applies a video to a certain DIV, it doesn't next it, but turns the actual div INTO the object itself. So I guess I just need a dual-layer system so I can keep at least one DIV intact.

Comment: $('#youtubecontainer'+suffix).remove('object');
    $('#youtubecontainer'+suffix).html('<div id=\"youtubepreview'+suffix+'\"></div>');

// and then re-embed a new video that will replace the old one, or leave it blank if the video is supposed to be blank. 

Thanks for the pointer towards the remove() function!

Answer (score 5):

SWFObject also has a [removeSWF method](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.removeSWF%28objElemIdStr%29) you can invoke if needed.

Assuming the SWF was embedded with the ID "mySwfID":

```
swfobject.removeSWF("mySwfID");
```